# Overriding the compareTo method with a class that is nested inside another class which extends Comparable

Tags: java, generics, comparable

I am tasked with writing my own PriorityQueue class in Java. It is based on LinkedLists. To quote the directions:

The type of the data stored in the nodes should be a generic type that is comparable. That is write for the class declaration: public class PriorityQueue (E extends Comparable)) -> note: the curly braces are meant to mean <>, whatever I write between <> is disappearing...

I will be using the PriorityQueue to write two other classes, one of type patient, the other of waitingRoom. This is where the compareTo method will come into play, as I sort the two classes into their individual PriorityQueues.

I have been defining the ListNode class inside of the PriorityQueue class itself, so I have a class within a class. Now comes the question:

Where am I going to implement/Override the inherited compareTo method from Comparable?

It can't get implemented in the PriorityQueue class because compareTo can only take one argument. Yet, this is where it seems like it should go, as this is the actual class extending Comparable.

If I implement it inside the ListNode class, well, I have no idea how I would. Do I turn ListNode into an interface? An AbstractClass?

Below is the quite novice code I have written, thanks for the help

```
    package hostpitalQueue;

import java.util.AbstractList;

public class PriorityQueue<E extends Comparable<E>>  {

    private ListNode front;

    public PriorityQueue() {
        front = null;
    }
    public PriorityQueue(ListNode n1) {
        front = n1;
    }



    //method for addingNode to beginning, 
    //perhaps overload method for next nodes?
    public void addNode(ListNode n1) {

        if(front == null) {
            front = n1;
        }else {
                //need to find last node and add n1 to it
                ListNode lastNode = findLastNode(n1);
                lastNode.addNode(n1);
            }
    }



    //need to compare, remember, this is a priorityqueue
    public ListNode findLastNode(ListNode n) {
        //compare the data of both
        //compare to front

        ListNode n1 = front;
        int i = n1.compareTo(n);
        //only do something here if n is higher priority
        if(i > 0) {
            E frontData = n1.data;
            E nodesData = n.data;
            ListNode holder = n1;
            front = n;
            n.next = holder;
            holder.previous = n;
        }else if(n1.next == null) {
            n1.next = n;
            n.previous = n1;
        }
        else {

            while(front.next != null) {
                n1 = front.next;
                //is n1 a higher priority?
                Integer ii = n1.compareTo(n);
                if(ii > 0) {
                    //this means that we should return the previous node, to insert
                    //before this one
                    return n1.previous;
                }
            }
        }
        return n1;
    }


    public class ListNode  {
        //contains a left and a right, as well as a data field
        public E data;
        public ListNode previous,next;


        //construct
        public ListNode() {
            data = null;
            previous = null;
            next = null;
        }

        //previous to next
        public ListNode(E data) {
            this.data = data;
            previous = null;
            next = null;
        }

        public ListNode(E data,ListNode n1) {
            this.data = data;
            previous = n1;
            next = null;
        }

        public ListNode(E data,ListNode n1,ListNode n2) {
            this.data = data;
            previous = n1;
            next = n2;
        }

        public void addNode(ListNode n1) {
            //gotta check if my next is null
            ListNode holder = null;
            if(this.next != null) {
                holder = this.next;
            }
            this.next = n1;
            n1.previous = this;
            n1.next = holder;
        }
        public int compareTo(ListNode n1) {
            return 0;
        }

        public void printMe() {
            System.out.println(this.data);
        }

    }







}
```

Comment: when you say you must use LinkedLists, do you mean you must use the class `LinkedList` or use linked lists?

Comment: I am assuming that I am to write my own LinkedList style of class since one of the specifications was using a doubly linked LinkedList, which doesn't seem to be the case with the already written LinkedList class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each class that you will use as element type of `PriorityQueue` must implement the `Comparable` interface and the `compareTo` method.

Note that as your `ListNode` class implements a `compareTo` method, you could have made it implement `Comparable<ListNode>`:

```
public class ListNode implements Comparable<ListNode>  {
```

...

```
    @Override
    public int compareTo(ListNode n1) {
        return data.compareTo(n1.data);
    }
```

Note that as you `ListNode` classe doesn't depend on an instance of `PriorityQueue`, you could have made it `static`; in which case, you would have had to declare a generic argument:

```
public static class ListNode<T extends Comparable<T>>
        implements Comparable<ListNode<T>>  {
    //contains a left and a right, as well as a data field
    public T data;
    public ListNode<T> previous,next;


    //construct
    public ListNode() {
        data = null;
        previous = null;
        next = null;
    }

    //previous to next
    public ListNode(T data) {
        this.data = data;
        previous = null;
        next = null;
    }

    public ListNode(T data,ListNode<T> n1) {
        this.data = data;
        previous = n1;
        next = null;
    }

    public ListNode(T data,ListNode<T> n1,ListNode<T> n2) {
        this.data = data;
        previous = n1;
        next = n2;
    }

    public void addNode(ListNode<T> n1) {
        //gotta check if my next is null
        ListNode<T> holder = null;
        if(this.next != null) {
            holder = this.next;
        }
        this.next = n1;
        n1.previous = this;
        n1.next = holder;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(ListNode<T> n1) {
        return data.compareTo(n1.data);
    }

    public void printMe() {
        System.out.println(this.data);
    }
}
```

class `ListNode` has fields, so you can't change it to an interface (why the hell would you do that anyway?)

You should perhaps ask yourself if you really need a doubly linked list and if a singly linked list would not suffice.

It is unclear in your question if you need to implement a linked list or if you could make use of the class `LinkedList` in which case you would not need the `ListNode` class: `PriorityQueue` would just encapsulate a `LinkedList<E>`.

Comment: I was wondering  the directions said for my PriorityQueue class to extend comparable, as I thought only interfaces could do so, maybe this was a type on the instructors part. The directions do not specify if I need to implement the linked list or encapsulate it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to compare two ListNodes, as in the line:

```
n1.compareTo(n)
```

You'd need to make it implement Comparable:

```
public class ListNode implements Comparable<ListNode> {
```

And implement the `compareTo` method as something like:

```
return this.data.compareTo(that.data);
```

(since you know the `data` is `Comparable`). But you would have to handle the case of null data.

---

Note that you should also declare your type variable on the top-level class as:

```
<E extends Comparable<? super E>>
```